# How can a user get write access to "/sys"?

Tags: permissions

I'd like to know what I need to do to enable a user to modify values in `/sys`. As it's a sysfs, changing file permissions is not an option (and I don't like to do it on every boot).

Comment: I don't think it can be done, cpufreq does not change it with a regular user, it communicates with a power daemon (which runs as root) via DBUS, it's the root process doing the change, not an user process.

Comment: True, but in the end the user has (indirect) write access to `/sys` without providing a password (in case of the cpufreq example) - which is what I want. So I guess the key here seems to be PolicyKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple python/dbus/polkit example on the [Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1359397) and changed the PolicyKit policy file defaults from

```
<defaults>
  <allow_any>auth_admin_keep</allow_any>
  <allow_inactive>auth_admin_keep</allow_inactive>
  <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
</defaults>
```

to

```
<defaults>
  <allow_any>no</allow_any>
  <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
  <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
</defaults>
```

With this change, an unprivileged user now can communicate with the service (running as root, thus being able to write to `/sys`) without having to type a password (possible risks?).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use sudo.  If you only want to give them permission to modify a specific value without general sudo access, then you can write a script that updates that particular value, and configure your sudoers file to allow the user permission ONLY to run that script as root.

Comment: I guess that's basically the same as my PolicyKit solution, which I prefer as I don't have to modify ´/etc/sudoers´.

Answer (score 2):

You should clarify what do you want to obtain.
Maybe you want to modify `/etc/sysctl.conf`, see `man sysctl` and `man sysctl.conf`

Comment: Well, I'd like to change a value on-the-fly as user. This has to be possible, as the cpufreq gnome applet does the same using a D-Bus service and a PolicyKit policy - how exactly (well, a rough outline) is what I'd like to know, not being good at reading code. :P

Comment: If you read the first man page, you saw that you can do it at runtime. As user you should use sudo.

Comment: I don't want to use `sudo`.

Comment: I don't think you can modify system parameters as a user.